# How to mock get_current_user in tornado for unittest?

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, tornado

I have a tornado web application. Many pages require a valid cookie to access. It makes it impossible to  test those handlers.

I want to use the `mock` library to mock the `tornado.web.RequestHandler.get_current_user` method. But I just cannot get right.

This is how I am doing right now:

```
class MyUT(tornado.testing.AsyncHTTPTestCase):
  def get_app(self):
    settings = {
      "template_path": '../../../templates',
      "cookie_secret": 'secret',
      "login_url": '/admin/login',
      "debug": True
    }

    return Application([
      (r'/admin/create/super', handlers.CreateSuperUserHandler)
    ], **settings)


  def testGet(self):
    with mock.patch.object(handlers.CreateSuperUserHandler, 'get_current_user') as m:
      m.return_value = {}
      response = self.fetch('/admin/create/super')

    print(response.body)
    self.assertGreater(response.body.index('create'), 0)
```

If I execute this code, I got a 404 error. Because I did not define the *login hanlder*. But I am expecting the mocked `get_current_user` method return a user object, so do not go to the *login page* while testing.

One strange thing I found is, if I add `m.assert_any_call()` in the `with` block, there's no assertion error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@authenticated` decorator redirects to the login page if `get_current_user` returns a falsy value. Try returning a non-empty dict.

You also use `handlers.CreateSuperUserHandler` in one place and `handlers.AdminArea.CreateSuperUserHandler` in another; are those the same class object?

Comment: Hi, I had to do the same thing.
Although I mocked (with patch) the method *get_current_user* , in **class BaseHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):** I continue to receive 403 from the route.
```@patch("api.views.base.BaseHandler")
  @gen_test
  async def testGetUserNotFound(self, mget):
    mget.get_current_user.return_value = 'test-username'
    response = requests.get(f"{self.base_url}/api/v5/users/123/devices")```